# Severe Linux Mouse Click and Window Focus Issues

Tags: linux, gnome, window-manager, mouse-click, window-focus

I have recently been trying to get a working Linux install on my main PC. My PC runs on a GTX 1060.

I've been having this issue where my mouse won't click properly in what looks to be a properly focused window. Instead it clicks in the window behind it or some other nonsense.

**I made a video in the end: https://youtu.be/n4gC7_r4C5k.**

This issue occurs on the latest Ubuntu, the latest Arch, the latest Debian and the latest Manjaro. I have not tested any other distributions. **The weirdest thing is, the problem does not occur on the install USB stick that I created for Ubuntu.**

This is not a hardware problem as far as I can see, I have tested multiple mice and also my laptop. All have the same or very similar problems.

I think only a video will do justice to how bad this actually is but I am going to try and explain it:

Right now, I am typing in a Firefox window, it's the only application open. I cannot click anything outside the window content, I can't even drag the title-bar. The Activities button (top left) doesn't work either. Also, if I hover over the Files shortcut in the favorites bar, it does not get highlighted.
The only way I can get out of the window is to <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd>.

I cannot for the life of me figure this out. Any help is **greatly** appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

The problem only occurs when there is multiple windows open and is slightly intermittent. The problem is there the majority of the time. It feels like the mouse is just really slow at changing the focused window.

Also another part of the problem: I can sometimes click on another window and the other window will come to the front. However the mouse still thinks it's in the old window. The keyboard acts in the new window.

Also, this problem sounds exactly the same as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/231755/ubuntu-odd-mouse-and-keyboard-behavior-when-window-gains-inner-focus?rq=1) super user question. Unplugging and replugging my mouse does not help though.

Comment: Since it's not a problem on the USB drive, it appears there is something left on the HDD taking focus (rootkit?). Have you tried tried completely formatting and partitioning the HDD, or is that not feasible as you're  dual-booting?

Comment: It was a completely clean drive.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a hardware problem. The mouse I was using (a Mad Catz Rat 3) used an abnormal scheme for clicks where one specific button would be "released" when clicked. The OS maintains this state even when a new mouse is plugged in hence trying multiple mice did not help.
Rebooting the machine after each mouse change was the solution to faultfinding this.

https://askubuntu.com/q/1115001/750012